# Serialize ASP.NET Web Service HTTP POST request results

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, serialization

I am trying to serialize my webmethod output (rename XML element with results),
So far

`[return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("results")]`

before method declaration works fine with soap requests, but I am looking for something that would work the same way with HTTP POST/GET requests as well (right now I get return class name as element name)

Comment: Are you serializing an existing object?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ASP.NET WebAPI? I think this is what you are looking for if you just beginning your project.
You can find a step-by-step tutorial here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api